# C++ on VScode is not working when I run my code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

So, I just recently started learning C++ and my cousin said that a good IDE was VScode. So, I installed VScode, downloaded the extensions that supported C++, and wrote my programs and got this:

```
"g++" is not recognized as an internal or external command.
```

what do I do here? I have looked at other questions that ask the same questions, but all of them mainly say to download a compiler like MinGW (Which I already have) and CygWin (also have downloaded this one). So what do I do?

Comment: Did you install the `g++` compiler?

Comment: What OS are you using ?

Comment: You have to install `g++` (at least on Windows), and tell VSCode where you put it.

Comment: ***but all of them mainly say to download a compiler like MinGW (Which I already have)*** You may already have mingw installed but your windows `PATH` environment variable does not contain the bin folder of your mingw.

Comment: I am using Windows, I have installed g++ (I think?)

Comment: My recommendation for someone starting out on a platform is to use the native tools if possible. On MS-Window that would be MS Visual Studio Community Edition - full featured and free. VS Code and MinGW will also work but you will have to work harder at setting up your development environment / tool-chain. Code::Blocks is also an option you could consider.

Comment: ***I am using Windows, I have installed g++ (I think?)*** Check your windows PATH environment variable to make sure it contains the mingw binary folder. Open a cmd.exe window and type `g++ --version` and see if you get the same error.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help! I finally got it to work! I don't know how, but I reinstalled MinGW and then did some stuff with the PATH environment var and got it to work.

Comment: how ?   i can get c++ working with visual studio, but not with VS code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the OS, you need to add path to g++ to PATH variable.
Check ~/.profile file?

Also check:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/576